# How to get a Lux value from "ambientIntensity" expressed in Lumens?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, light

I have a ARSCNView where I get the `ambientIntensity` (in lumens), but I need to get the lux value.

If 1 lux is equals 1 lumens/m2, how I can get the lux value for the scene?

Answer (score 2):

## Lux value depends on the size of your scene.

ARKit developer documentation [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arlightestimate/2878308-ambientintensity):

> The value of `ambientIntensity` instance property is based on the internal exposure compensation of the camera device, and scaled to be appropriate for use in rendering architectures that use realistic lighting metrics. A value of `1000 lumens` represents **neutral lighting**.

An article, for instance, from [Suprabeam](https://www.eur.webshop.suprabeam-shop.com/uk/light) website says:

> `Lux` is a unit of light measurement where the area is also taken into account. One lux equals one lumen/m2, in other words - light intensity in a specific area. So:

```
/*   1000 lux = 1000 lumen/m2   */
```

It means that a flux of 1000 lumens, concentrated into an area of 1 square metre, produces a very bright illuminance of 1000 lux.

Also it means that the same 1000 lumens, spread out over 100 square metres, produces a much more dimmer illuminance of only 10 lux.

Hence, under ideal conditions it looks like this:

```
let luxIntensity = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate!.ambientIntensity
        
print("Lux Intensity: \(String(describing: luxIntensity! / 100))")

/*   Lux Intensity: 9.706215858459473   */
```

But in real environment there's always decay of light (which is described by [**Inverse Square Law**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law)).

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear to be the case that ARKit's `ambientIntensity` corresponds to the actual photopic quantity. When I checked this value under bright day light or in a dark room, the value initially increased or decreased (as expected) but eventually leveled off to about 1000. Furthermore, "intensity" is misleading because that's actually lumens per steradian. Unfortunately, official Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arlightestimate/2878308-ambientintensity) as of April 2020 still leaves a lot to be desired.

*Lumens* is a quantity of flux, so it characterizes the total amount of light emitted by a source. Capturing the flux in your scene isn't physically possible with just a camera because only light making it through the cameras entrance pupil is included.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you figured out how to get a real light amount using ARkit?

Comment: First, you need to define what you mean by "real light amount". I think the illuminance (watts/m^2) would make the most sense. You can only get a rough estimate of the illuminance with just a camera. ARKit won't provide you with this out of the box. You will need to get the sample buffer representing the current frame and get the exposure time (t) and ISO speed rating (s) from the metadata. Illuminance (lux) can then be estimated by pi * 12.5 * (f/#)^2 / (t * s)